# Different Image widths in Html for Android Tablet and Phone

Tags: android, html, image, android-assets

I have an android app which runs on tablet and phone. My content is loading html files from the assets folder. My problem is I want different image sizes on tablet and phone.

here is the code for the image on phone.

```
<img src="check_yes_tick_parent.png" width="8%"/>
```

However this is too wide on tablet and ideally I would like the width to be 3%.

I know I could make two html files for each one. i.e one for phone and one for tablet. But is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css and media query for this then you don't need to have 2 or more html file.

For example:

At html:

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

At css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(check_yes_tick_parent.png);
}
@media screen and (width: 768px) and (height: 1004px) {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(check_yes_tick_parent_for_pad.png);
}
```

You can refer to [CSS3 @media Rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)